# You cannot specify a scheduled publish time on a non-scheduled post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to Post Scheduled Post in facebook. but am having the following error.

```
$data = array(
    'name' => $_POST['title'],
    'message' => $_POST['status'],
    'scheduled_publish_time'=> strtotime('2017-09-28 09:00:00'),
    'published'=>'false'
);
$fb->post('/'.$_POST['grp'].'/feed', $data, $_SESSION['token'])
```

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthenticationException' with message '(#100) You cannot specify a scheduled publish time on a non-scheduled post.'

Comment: `'false'` as a string value is _truthy_, so with `'published'=>'false'` you have implicitly set this option to `true`. Use `'published'=>false` instead.

Comment: 1st time i have given 'published'=>false but its not working. Error (You cannot specify a scheduled publish time on a non-scheduled post

)

Comment: Wait, does `$_POST['grp']` mean you are trying to post to a _group_ feed? You can not schedule posts to a group feed (at least not via API, does the UI even provide that?) - that is for posts to a page’s feed only.

Comment: $_POST['grp'] is Group ID. Am trying to post a feed in to a Group with Scheduled time. If there is any possible to schedule time using Graph API?

Comment: No, _as I just said_, that is not possible ... You could of course set up a system that posts at the right time to begin with - a cron job that executes a script every minute (or five minutes, or whatever “resolution” your scheduling needs would work with), checks which posts are to post “now”, and then makes those posts.

Comment: Thank You i will go with cron job.